# How to compare two files containing numbers in UNIX?

Tags: unix, compare, diff

I have two files. First file contains 500000 records (numbers) and second file contains 4000000 records(numbers).

<sup>Numbers are not in a single line.They are one by one like in a column of Excel sheet.</sup>

File 1 contains below numbers:

```
1483
2111
2973
3214
3503
3639
3747
4042
4351
4766
4809
5950
6616
6899
7559
7940
8205
8262
8291
```

File 2 contains below numbers:

```
1483
2111
2973
3214
3503
3639
3747
4042
4351
4766
4809
5950
6616
6899
7559
7940
8205
8262
8291
9000
9163
9229
9497
9719
0409
0421
0698
0924
1059
```

I want to find how many records from first file are not present in the records containing second file. I tried to compare using Excel but my laptop was going into hung state many a times. Also, I tried with diff command in UNIX but did not reach to expected output.
Please someone help me to figure this out in UNIX as it will take less time than other methods.

Comment: To get a good answer, it'll be useful if you give a sample of your data and an example of what you expect as an output. If it's simply a long list of numbers, is either sorted?

Comment: Hi Sobrique,File 1 contains below numbers:1483
2111
2973
3214
3503
3639
3747
4042
4351
4766
4809
5950
6616
6899
7559
7940
8205
8262
8291
File 2 contains below numbers:1483
2111
2973
3214
3503
3639
3747
4042
4351
4766
4809
5950
6616
6899
7559
7940
8205
8262
8291
9000
9163
9229
9497
9719
0409
0421
0698
0924
1059.

Comment: Can you edit those into your question? Looks like purely numeric, sorted into order. This makes the problem a lot easier.

Comment: Only the count: `diff -u  file_one file_two | grep -c  '^-[0-9]'`

Comment: Can you please explain how " diff -u file_one file_two | grep -c '^-[0-9]' "  will work?

Comment: It will work excellently! (given file_on and file_two are sorted) for the rest: `man diff` and `man grep`

Comment: Won't diff/grep work per line, where the post indicates multiple numbers on the same line?

Comment: 500000 numbers on one line? In that case: first first replace all whitespace by '\n'  in both files.

Comment: Numbers are not in a single line.They are one by one like in a column of excel sheet

Comment: Ok. That's why it's important to include input data as a sample. EXACTLY as it looks in the file (including linefeeds). `diff` will do what you want in that scenario.

Comment: Can you please suggest exact command which I should use to get all records from first file which are not present in second file. I tried " diff -u file_one file_two | grep -c '^-[0-9]' " but it is giving me only the count. I need records.

Answer (score 1):

The data in `file 2` is not fully sorted; there are some numbers starting with 0 and 1 at the end.  Consequently, you really need to sort the numbers, and then you can use [`comm`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/comm.html) with Bash (Korn shell, Z Shell) and [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```
comm <(sort file.1) <(sort file.2)
```

This will print numbers that appear in `file.1` only in column 1, numbers that appear in `file.2` only in column 2 (indented by a tab), and number appearing in both in column 3 (indented by two tabs).

You can suppress a columns 2 and 3 with the `-23` option, leaving you with the numbers in `file.1` only:

```
comm -23 <(sort file.1) <(sort file.2)
```

And if you want to count how many such numbers there are, then:

```
comm -23 <(sort file.1) <(sort file.2) | wc -l
```

If you don't have process substitution, then you need to sort the two files separately.  If you don't need the original files in the original order again, then you can use:

```
sort -o file.1 file.1
sort -o file.2 file.2
comm -23 file.1 file.2 | wc -l
```

The alternatives are legion.

Answer (score 1):

Awk might provide some options for solving this one as well.  Here's one.

This solution doesn't have the overhead of running a couple of massive `sort` functions as required by the `comm` solution with bash process substitution...  Though it does require that your system be beefy enough to load all of your larger file into memory for processing.

```
$ awk -f '

  # populate an array with the contents of the first file only...
  NR==FNR { a[$1]; next; }

  # then delete any array elements that are in the second file...
  { delete a[$1]; }

  # finally, display our results.
  END {
    for (i in a) count++;
    printf("Count: %d entries\n", count);
    for (i in a) printf("%s\n", a[i]);
  }

  ' file2 file1
```

The idea here is that we'll step through `file2` (the longer file) and slurp it into an array, then we remove everything from that array that appears in `file` (the shorter file), and then count and print what remains.

Proviso #1: As stated above, this requires that you have available memory to store all of `file2` in an array in memory.  You'll have to determine whether that's possible on your own.  (Perhaps by trying it!)

Proviso #2: I haven't tested this, even for syntax errors.  YMMV.  :)